# 大規模なRubyのプログラムで使用しているArrayをNumo::NArrayに全て変更したい

Tags: ruby

少々変な質問をさせていただきます．

### アドバイスを主に伺いたいです．

プログラムの高速化をしたく，Rubyの標準ライブラリ`Array`から`Numo::NArray`に実装変更したいのですが，私の現在のRubyのプログラムが大規模でありまして，例えば，`aaa.rb`内で`Array`で定義した配列で様々な四則演算を行い，その結果を`bbb.rb`内のメソッドでまた四則演算を行ったりと複雑なプログラムです．
そういったプログラムに対して一部の`Array`を`Numo::NArray`にそのまま実装変更したら大量のエラーが発生しそうで怖いです．

一部の`Array`を`Numo::NArray`にそのまま実装変更しても問題はないのでしょうか．
`Array`と`Numo::NArray`は互換性はありますでしょうか．

かなり抽象的な質問であり，私がどのようなコードを書いているかにも依存する質問ですが，質問から汲み取れる範囲で良いのでご教授お願いします．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby/NArrayのファンです。
NArrayに興味を持ってくれる人がいてとても嬉しいのです。

高速計算をしたいのですね。NArrayにはうってつけの課題ではないでしょうか。
ただNArrayがRubyのArrayとは全然違うのも事実なので、ちょっとずつ変更していく必要があるでしょう。

```rb
# Rubyの配列 → NArray
na = Numo::DFloat.cast(array)

# NArray → Rubyの配列
ruby_array = na.to_a
```

と書けば相互変換できますので、少しずつ置き換えていきましょう。
個人的な経験では、Rubyの配列とNArrayの相互変換はそれほど時間がかからず、
計算の高速化の効果の方が高いです。

numo-linalg
numo-gsl
numo-fftw
numo-ffte
などの便利なライブラリもありますよ。

NArrayの全く初心者の方は以下のQiitaエントリーを一読してみてください。
https://qiita.com/kojix2/items/0bc5efda0f65e58693a0

わからないことがあったらぜひGitHubのNArrayのissueに書き込んだり、

日本語がいいならSciRubyのSlackで質問することもできます。
https://sciruby-slack.herokuapp.com/

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます．頑張ってみます！

Comment: 過去の質問を追ってみると、複素数のNArray→Rubyへの変換が遅いかもしれないという投稿がありますね。もしもその種の課題を見つけたら、ぜひ本家のGitHubのissueに投稿してみてください。わりと改善されたりします。

Answer (score 1):

`Numo::NArray`は高速な`Array`ではありません。したがって機械的な置き換えもできません。